# Implementing security restful API for social app

Tags: c#, objective-c, oauth

I'm developing a social network. I have a RESTful API coded in C# and my front end application on objective C. My architecture is very simple:

> Iphone Users (mobile app) < - > RESTful API < - >  DATABASE

I want to implement authentication for my service and to make is secure. Also i want to be able to retain something in the phone that tells if it is logged or not and with which account.

I've been reading and i found out that oauth is standard for this. i have a lot of questions that i don't understand. There is suppose to be a previously shared between the resource owner and the server.... who's the resource owner in this case? the user itself? and i imagine the server is the RESTful API. About the security token, is it coded in the mobile app? and in the server?

About the token. does the token retain information about my login? I mean, is the token what tells me what user I am while I use the app? this is what differences two users when they ask for example GetMyFriends ?

and for last, whats an API Key and how do I implement it and use it?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question will require a book volume to provide every possible answer, so I'll try to answer a small bit of questions I can and hopefully that will direct you on the right track.

1) How do I make my client-server connection secure?
Use SSL certificate for the HTTP server that hosts your API.

2) How do I implement my authentication and keep track of which user is currently active in the system?
There are numerous ways to implement your own authentication and I'll only provide a short description. Use two instances of UITextField to get user's username (or e-mail) and password. Send those values to your REST API. To keep track of a currently active User you'll either nee to implement a fairly complex solution using CoreData, where you would create a User entity and have something like an "isActive" boolean value that you'll set to YES once a given user logs in. Keeping it a bit simpler you can just store an NSDictionary representation of your active user's parameters you get from server after authentication.

3) Is oAuth standard for this?
No, do not use oAuth for your own application. You only need to use oAuth to provide third-party applications an ability to log in users into your web application. xAuth is standard - request authentication credentials from user via UI in an application and send those credentials via your API to server and process the response.

4) About the token. does the token retain information about my login? i mean, is the token what tells me what user i am while i use the app? this is what differences two users when they ask for example GetMyFriends ?
Answer #2 should answer how do you know which user sends request. You can retain an information about the currently active user by setting the values you're interested in in the current session, for example - user_id, so you can distinguish which user sends the GetMyFriends request.

I know this doesn't even remotely covers the whole area of what you're asking about, but you need to do a bit better research on this topic.

Comment: Thank you it helped me more than you think :), im doing exactly what you told me and its working. Im planing on buying a good ssl certificate. about the tokens, yes, they retain information about your login, its a string that each user need to send with each request and that is stored in the server so i can match the token with the user.

Comment: @RukiaKuchiki Glad the answer could help you. Let me know if you have any other questions on the topic. I've built a couple of social networking applications and surely will be able to give you an advice or two. You can view the projects I've worked on in my profile. If you find a need to build any similar functionality feel free to ask me about implementation.